# Given starting network, how many subnets with 128 address can you form

Tags: networking, subnet

Given a starting network of 172,20.12/24, how many subnets with 128 addresses can you form?

I thought the answer was 8 because 2^8 - 2 = 254 > 128 but that's incorrect

It also asks for the first subnet and mask. I got 172.20.12.16/24 Is that correct?

Comment: i personally suggest you to read this https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing, and about your question, how many subnets with 128 address using a /24 network, its simply = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 172.20.12/24 (can also be written as 172.20.12.0/24, or as 172.20.12.0 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0) you can form two subnets with roughly 128 address each:

Subnet 1: 172.20.12.0/25
  subnet mask: 255.255.255.128
  first address (often used as the router/gateway address): 172.20.12.1
  last unicast address: 172.20.12.126
  broadcast address: 172.20.12.127

Subnet 2: 172.20.12.128/25
  subnet mask: 255.255.255.128
  first address (often used as the router/gateway address): 172.20.12.129
  last unicast address: 172.20.12.254
  broadcast address: 172.20.12.255

The trick is to look at the address, especially the "host" section of the address, in binary.

If you have 172.20.12.0/24, in binary it would be:

```
                    Address: 10101100.00010100.00001100.00000000
24-bit subnet mask (24 1's): 11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000
```

So you've got the last 8 bits (the entire last octet) to use for host addresses or subnetting.

2^8 = 256, so dividing that up into groups of 128 and you get two groups.

If you extend the subnet mask by one more bit (from 24 to 25 bits), you now have two subnets of about 128 addresses.

In binary, that subnet mask is `11111111.11111111.11111111.10000000`. That first bit of the last octet is the 128's place bit, so, to write it in "dotted decimal" form, it would be 255.255.255.128.

This subnet mask leaves 7 bits for the host section, and 2^7 = 128.

However, if your instructor is being a stickler, he'd point out that the address where the host part (in binary) is all zeros is semi-reserved as the "network number", and the address where the host part (in binary) is all ones is the subnet broadcast address, so you'd end up with `128 - 2 = 126` addresses (and then burn at least one more for a gateway, etc., leaving even fewer addresses for leaf-node host devices.

So the most precise answer to the question would be that a /24 only leaves room for one subnet with fully 128 unicast host addresses, and that is the whole /24 itself. It actually has room for up to 254 unicast host addresses, but since the largest blocks you can split it into don't quite hold 128 unicast host addresses each, you don't have the luxury of splitting it up if you have a hard requirement of 128 unicast host addresses per subnet.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering :). I entered those values but it was still marked as wrong. I think the my teacher put the answer in a different form. I have a couple of questions though. How did you know that 2 subnets can be formed with 128 addresses? Is it because 128 * 2 = 256? and How did you get /25 as the subnet mask?

Comment: @Matt: A /24 has 256 addresses. 256/128 = 2. /25 comes from /32-7. It also comes from /24+1. I think you might want to re-learn the basics of subnetting.